# Split class property in two properties

Tags: python, oop

I solve a system of two equations in a class property, and it returns the solution -- values of two variables. I'd like both values be a properties of the class -- how do I achieve this without solving the system twice? Here's an example

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

class Test(object):
    pass

    def ab(self):
        print("Calc!")
        a = 1
        b = 2
        return [a,b]

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.ab()[0]


    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.ab()[1]

test = Test()

print(test.a)
print(test.b)
```

It outputs:

```
Calc!
1
Calc!
2
```

so it actually "solved" the system of equations (`ab` property) twice. If it had solved it once, than the output would be:

```
Calc!
1
2
```

How do I achieve this?

**Edit**

Example with a system:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import scipy
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, c, d):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

    def ab(self):
        print("Calc!")
        result = fsolve(lambda x: [
                    x[0] + 2*x[1] + self.c
                , 3*x[0] -   x[1] + self.d
            ], [1,1])
        return result

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.ab()[0]


    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.ab()[1]

test = Test(-5,2)

print(test.a)
print(test.b)
```

Gives:

```
Calc!
0.142857142857
Calc!
2.42857142857
```

I want it to solve a system only once:

```
Calc!
0.142857142857
2.42857142857
```

**Edit 2**

Real code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse, os, sys

# ==============
## parsing args:

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

argsLip = parser.add_argument_group('Properties of lipid:')
argsLip.add_argument('-A', '--area',
    help = "incompressible area, Å² (default to %(default)s)", 
    dest = 'A_n',
    action = 'store',
    type = float,
    default = 20.0,
    )
argsLip.add_argument('-L',
    help = "basic length in Å (default to %(default)s)", 
    dest = 'L',
    action = 'store',
    type = float,
    default = 15.0,
    )
argsLip.add_argument('-K', '--K-coef',
    help = "bending rigidity in kTL (default to %(default)s)", 
    dest = 'K_f_coef',
    action = 'store',
    type = float,
    default = 0.33,
    )

argsMem = parser.add_argument_group('Properties of membrane:')
argsMem.add_argument('-g', '--gamma',
    help = "surface tension, erg/cm² (default to %(default)s)", 
    dest = 'γ',
    action = 'store',
    type = float,
    default = 30.0,
    )

argsEnv = parser.add_argument_group('Properties of environment:')
argsEnv.add_argument('-T', '--temperature',
    help = "temperature, K (default to %(default)s)", 
    dest = 'T',
    action = 'store',
    type = float,
    default = 323.0,
    )

argsCalc = parser.add_argument_group('Calc options:')
argsCalc.add_argument('-a', '--a-trial',
    help = "trial value of a to be used in nsolve (default to %(default)s)", 
    dest = 'a_trial',
    action = 'store',
    type = float,
    default = 2.0,
    )

args = parser.parse_args()


# =========
## imports:

# symbolic:
import sympy
from sympy import symbols, solve, nsolve, pprint, diff, S, Function
from sympy import sqrt as Sqrt
sympy.init_printing(pretty_print=True, use_unicode=True, wrap_line=False, no_global=True)

# numeric:
import scipy
from scipy import sqrt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

# constants:
from scipy import pi as π

from scipy.constants import k as k_SI
k = k_SI * 10**7 # J/K → erg/K



# =========
## program:

class MonoFlexible_symbolic(object):
    "This class initiates common symbolic expressions to be used in all MonoFlexible classes."
    def __init__(self):

        a, l = symbols("a l", real=True, positive=True)

        b = Function('b')(a, l)
        ν = Function('ν')(l)

        equation = (
                  3 / (4 * b)
                + 1 / ( 2 * Sqrt(2) * b**(S(3)/4) )
                - ν * ( Sqrt(a) - 1 )**2
            )

        equation_diff_a  = equation.diff(a)
        equation_diff_a2 = equation_diff_a.diff(a)
        equation_diff_l  = equation.diff(l)        .subs(ν.diff(l)  , -3*ν)
        equation_diff_l2 = equation_diff_l.diff(l) .subs(ν.diff(l,2), 12*ν)
        equation_diff_al = equation_diff_a.diff(l) .subs(ν.diff(l)  , -3*ν)

        db_da    = solve( equation_diff_a  , b.diff(a)         )[0]
        d2b_da2  = solve( equation_diff_a2 , b.diff(a,2)       )[0]
        db_dl    = solve( equation_diff_l  , b.diff(l)         )[0]
        d2b_d2l  = solve( equation_diff_l2 , b.diff(l,2)       )[0]
        d2b_dadl = solve( equation_diff_al , b.diff(a).diff(l) )[0]

        # print("db_da =")
        # pprint(
        #     db_da
        # )

        # print("d2b_da2 =")
        # pprint("d2b_da2 =",
        #     d2b_da2
        # )

        # print("db_dl =")
        # pprint(
        #     db_dl
        # )

        # print("d2b_dl2 =")
        # pprint(
        #     d2b_d2l
        # )

        # print("d2b_dadl =")
        # pprint(
        #     cancel(d2b_dadl[0])
        # )

        self.db_da_func = lambda aa, bb, νν: db_da.subs({
                  a: aa
                , b: bb
                , ν: νν
            }).evalf()

        self.d2b_da2_func = lambda aa, bb, νν: d2b_da2.subs({
                  a: aa
                , b: bb
                , ν: νν
            }).evalf()

        self.db_dl_func = lambda aa, bb, νν: db_dl.subs({
                  a: aa
                , b: bb
                , ν: νν
            }).evalf()

        self.d2b_d2l_func = lambda aa, bb, νν: d2b_dl2.subs({
                  a: aa
                , b: bb
                , ν: νν
            }).evalf()

        self.d2b_dadl_func = lambda aa, bb, νν: d2b_dadl.subs({
                  a: aa
                , b: bb
                , ν: νν
            }).evalf()


class MonoFlexible(MonoFlexible_symbolic):
    def __init__(self,
        γ        : "Surface tension of the membrane, erg/cm²",
        T        : "Temperature, K",
        L        : "Length of the hydrocarbon chain, Å",
        A_n      : "Non-compressible area of the lipid, Å²",
        a_trial  : "Initial value for fsolve, default to 2.0" = None,
        K_f_coef : "K_f = k T L * K_f_coef, default to 1/3" = None,
        )       -> "Calculates thermodynamic properties of flexible string":

        super().__init__()

        self.__γ        = γ
        self.__T        = T
        self.__L        = L
        self.__A_n      = A_n
        self.__a_trial  = a_trial
        self.__K_f_coef = K_f_coef

    @property
    def A_n_Å2(self):
        return self.__A_n

    @property
    def A_n(self):
        return self.__A_n * 10**(-16) # Å² → cm²

    @property
    def L_Å(self):
        return self.__L

    @property
    def L(self):
        return self.__L * 10**(-8) # Å → cm

    @property
    def γ(self):
        return self.__γ

    @property
    def T(self):
        return self.__T

    @property
    def a_trial(self):
        "Initial value for numerical equation solving function to find area per lipid."
        a_trial = self.__a_trial or 2.0
        return a_trial

    @property
    def K_f_coef(self):
        K_f_coef = self.__K_f_coef or 1/3
        return K_f_coef

    @property
    def K_f(self):
        "Rigidity of the string."
        return k * self.T * self.L * self.K_f_coef

    @property
    def ν(self):
        return self.K_f * self.A_n / (
            π * k * self.T * self.L**3
            )

    @property
    def ab(self):
        print("Calc!")
        ab = fsolve( lambda x: [
                  3 / ( 4 * x[1] )
                + 1 / ( 2 * sqrt(2) * x[1]**(3/4) )
                - self.ν * (sqrt(x[0]) - 1)**2
                ,
                - k * self.T / self.A_n * self.db_da_func(x[0], x[1], self.ν) * self.ν * (sqrt(x[0]) - 1)**2
                - self.γ
            ]
            , [2., 300.] )
        return ab

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.ab[0]

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.ab[1]


# ======
## calc:

def main():

    flexible_kwargs = {
        "γ"        : args.γ,
        "T"        : args.T,
        "L"        : args.L,
        "A_n"      : args.A_n,
        "a_trial"  : args.a_trial,
        "K_f_coef" : args.K_f_coef,
    }

    flexible = MonoFlexible(**flexible_kwargs)

    print( "ν = {ν:.5f}".format(ν=flexible.ν) )
    print( "a = {a:.2f}".format(a=flexible.a) )
    print( "b = {b:.2f}".format(b=flexible.b) )


# python code run faster in a function:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Works with default parameters, so in order to test it -- just run it.

Comment: Your example is far-removed from real use, so it is hard to ascertain the constraints of the problem. For a given instance, is there only one solution ever? Why are these properties and not normal attributes or methods? What is the real problem you're solving?

Comment: @MikeGraham: but it says it all... I solve a system of two equation, there's only one solution, and I use scipy's fsolve, which returns the solutions as a list (or an array). But I want both solutions to be properties of the instance, so I'm looking for a way to rebind a list returned by class method as two properties.

Comment: @MikeGraham: I added an example with the dummy system of equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're just trying to cache the solution. Here's a way to do that that involves creating another property:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def solution(self):
        try:
            return self._solution
        except AttributeError:
            self._solution = self.ab()
            return self._solution

    def ab(self):
        print("Calc!")
        a = 1
        b = 2
        return [a,b]

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.solution[0]

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.solution[1]

test = Test()

print(test.a)
print(test.b)
```

Output:

```
Calc!
1
2
```

#### *Update!*

In Python 3.8 a built-in decorator to do this was added to the standard library named [`functools.cached_property()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) that makes implementing this scheme in an easier and more succinct way (plus it's thread-safe):

```
import functools

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @functools.cached_property
    def ab(self):
        print("Calc!")
        a = 1
        b = 2
        return [a,b]

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.ab[0]

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.ab[1]
```

Comment: In my production code it works if I use `if self.solution == None:` instead of `if not self.solution:`. Otherwise it says `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Comment: Worked fine for me using Python 3.4.3. However, if you have to change it, make it `if self.solution is None`. I've updated my answer to do this as well as be more concise.

Answer (score 1):

assigning the properties as the results are created could be a way to go

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3

class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def ab(self):
        print("Calc!")
        self._a = a = 1
        self._b = b = 2
        return [a,b]

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value



    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value

test = Test()
results = test.ab()
print(test.a)
print(test.b)
```

Comment: Doesn't work on my machine: `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Comment: Now it says `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Comment: I forgot to make the property itself "private", but now it works

Comment: yep, now it works. But one needs `results = test.ab()` line for this to work.

Comment: It can be run from the \__init__\ and if it needs to be inherited, you can use the `super ` function or override that behavior

Answer (score 0):

Your current class doesn't have any statefulness at all, so it doesn't seem like an example of good class design. Its exact operation is completely hard-coded...it is hard to know what advantage you get from having it.

Perhaps what you want is something more along the lines of

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = fsolve(lambda x: [
                    x[0] + 2*x[1] - 5
                , 3*x[0] -   x[1] + 2
            ], [1,1])
```

Comment: It's no good to calculate under `__init__`, because it breaks inheritance. I don't need it right now, but I might need it later. In reality I have parameters under `__init__`, and the system is solved for these parameters.

Comment: @Adobe, How does that apply to `__init__` but not to `ab`? How would the needed inheritance look? What does the real class look like--is it stateful? is it parametric in any way?

Comment: I edited the Edit. Please see it's `__init__`. This way I can inhere `ab` method, and if some method uses it, it all will work, but if I put `ab` under `__init__` it won't work.

Comment: @Adobe, inheritance would be a very, very unfortunate solution to such a problem if that's what you want to change. Can you post your actual, real code with all names and operations intact?